# Civivolunteer Opportunities not showing

Tags: civivolunteer

I've seen similar posts but have not found a solution.

I've created an event and have provided volunteer opportunities for that event. When someone goes to the page to volunteer for an event, the volunteer opportunities do not show. At the bottom, it shows:

"No results found. Please try different search criteria."

Now, what is weird when logged in as a Superuser, it works properly. Every other user group does not work and shows the above result. Upon searching, I saw a post regarding permissions:
[CiviVolunteer - Joomla - permission issue with multiple volunteer opportunities](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15889/civivolunteer-joomla-permission-issue-with-multiple-volunteer-opportunities)

I've granted permission to the AJAX API but the opportunities still do not appear. Because super user works, it would lead me to believe it is a permissions issue but I cannot locate the proper change. Any suggestions?

Here is what I see:
http://blueribbonproject.org/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/vol/&Itemid=2001#/volunteer/opportunities?project=13&dest=event&hideSearch=always

Comment: Petednz, I did spot that and it appears to me that all permissions are the way they should be. With that said, I noticed something different while trying to correct this. When I have one single volunteer opportunity under "Set Shift" defined, it shows. Adding additional opportunities or anything other than set shift results in no opportunities showing. Note the differences in the following 2 screenshots: http://blueribbonproject.org/images/Image1.jpg       http://blueribbonproject.org/images/Image2.jpg

Answer (score 0):

[CiviVolunteer](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civivolunteer) mentions CiviVolunteer: register to volunteer permission. Did you spot that?

Answer (score 0):

Permissions settings done for ACL? (I'm on Joomla so this is how i do it)
Administer / Users and Permissions / Access Control / Joomla Access Control
Select your user group (in my case "Registered".
CiviCRM: access AJAX API - Allowed
CiviVolunteer: register to volunteer - Allowed
CiviVolunteer: edit own volunteer projects - Allowed
CiviVolunteer: edit all volunteer projects - Allowed